# GCP User defined metric not receiving / displaying any data

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, time-series, metrics

I have created a user-defined metric using the Python API template given by Google. The metric is supposed to record a number (called data) produced by a cloud function once a day. I have already created a metric descriptor named `rs_metric_test`, and when I try to publish a time series to the descriptor, I don't see any data from the UI perspective.

This is the code for the descriptor and creating/pushing the time series:

```
client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_name = "project_name"
descriptor = ga_metric.MetricDescriptor()
descriptor.type = "custom.googleapis.com/rs_metric_test"
descriptor.metric_kind = ga_metric.MetricDescriptor.MetricKind.GAUGE
descriptor.value_type = ga_metric.MetricDescriptor.ValueType.DOUBLE
descriptor.description = "This is a simple example of a custom metric."

labels = ga_label.LabelDescriptor()
labels.key = "TestLabel"
labels.value_type = ga_label.LabelDescriptor.ValueType.STRING
labels.description = "This is a test label"
descriptor.labels.append(labels)

descriptor = client.create_metric_descriptor(
    name=project_name, metric_descriptor=descriptor
)
print("Created {}.".format(descriptor.name))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def create_time_series(client, data):
    series = monitoring_v3.TimeSeries()
    series.metric.type = f"custom.googleapis.com/rs_metric_test"
    series.resource.type = "global"
    series.resource.labels["project_id"] = "project_name"

    series.metric.labels["function"] = "function_name"
    series.metric.labels["data"] = data
    series.metric.labels["TestLabel"] = "test label for testing"
    now = time.time()
    seconds = int(now)
    nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
    interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
        {"end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos}}
    )
    point = monitoring_v3.Point({"interval": interval, "value": {"double_value": 3.14}})
    series.points = [point]
    client.create_time_series(name="project_name", time_series=[series])
    print("time series created")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

replay_metric_client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
create_time_series(replay_metric_client, "partner", str(capture_percent))
```

When `create_time_series` is called, It runs without exception, but I never see any sign of data being sent to the metric in the UI. I've made log-based metrics before but this is my first user defined metric, so I'm pretty lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your log based metrics definitions? And the orginal full logs that you want to catch?

Comment: These are not log based metrics, they are user defined (You can tell the difference because there is no UI to create user defined metrics, unlike log based metrics). The data that the metric is catching is the "series" object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some experimentation I found a solution. I will include a working example of the code below:

```
/* First we create the metric descriptor */

def create_descriptor():
client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_name = "projectname"
descriptor = ga_metric.MetricDescriptor()
descriptor.type = "custom.googleapis.com/rs_metric_test"
descriptor.metric_kind = ga_metric.MetricDescriptor.MetricKind.GAUGE
descriptor.value_type = ga_metric.MetricDescriptor.ValueType.DOUBLE
descriptor.description = "Description of this metric descriptor."

descriptor = client.create_metric_descriptor(
    name=project_name, metric_descriptor=descriptor
)
print("Created {}.".format(descriptor.name))



/* next create the actual metric */
def create_time_series(data):
series = monitoring_v3.TimeSeries()
series.metric.type = f"custom.googleapis.com/rs_metric_test"
series.resource.type = "global"
series.resource.labels["project_id"] = "projectname"
series.metric.labels["test_label"] = "this is a test label"
now = time.time()
seconds = int(now)
nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
    {"end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos}}
)
point = monitoring_v3.Point({"interval": interval, "value": {"double_value": data}})
series.points = [point]
monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient().create_time_series(name="projectname", time_series=[series])
print("time series created")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).